# Adding Scroll Panel makes Text Area Disappear

Tags: java

I have a telephone simulation program which contains a frame that has a speaker text area, a button panel, and a microphone text area. I am trying to add vertical scroll bars to the two texts areas. But when I do that, both of the text areas seems to fold in and disappear. Could anyone please explain what the problem is?
Here's my telephone class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
   Presents a phone GUI for the voice mail system.  When multiple Telephones
   are created, closing the last one will exit the program.
*/
public class Telephone
{
       private JTextArea speakerField;
       private JScrollPane scrollSpeaker;
       private Connection connect;
       private static int numberOfPhones = 0;
   /**
      Constructs a telephone with a speaker, keypad, and microphone.
   */
   public Telephone()
   {

      numberOfPhones = numberOfPhones + 1;
      JPanel speakerPanel = new JPanel();
      speakerPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      speakerPanel.add(new JLabel("Speaker:"),
         BorderLayout.NORTH);
      speakerField = new JTextArea(10, 25);
      scrollSpeaker = new JScrollPane(speakerField);
      scrollSpeaker.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

      speakerPanel.add(speakerField, 
         BorderLayout.CENTER);

      speakerPanel.add(scrollSpeaker);

      String keyLabels = "123456789*0#";
      JPanel keyPanel = new JPanel();
      keyPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 3));
      for (int i = 0; i < keyLabels.length(); i++)
      {
         final String label = keyLabels.substring(i, i + 1);
         JButton keyButton = new JButton(label);
         keyPanel.add(keyButton);
         keyButton.addActionListener(new
            ActionListener()
            {
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
               {
                  connect.dial(label);
               }
            });
      }

      final JTextArea microphoneField = new JTextArea(10, 25);
      final JScrollPane scrollMic = new JScrollPane(microphoneField);
      scrollMic.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

      JButton speechButton = new JButton("Send speech");
      speechButton.addActionListener(new
         ActionListener()
         {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
               connect.record(microphoneField.getText());
               microphoneField.setText("");
            }
         });

      JButton hangupButton = new JButton("Hangup");
      hangupButton.addActionListener(new
         ActionListener()
         {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
               connect.hangup();
            }
         });

      JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
      buttonPanel.add(speechButton);
      buttonPanel.add(hangupButton);

      JPanel microphonePanel = new JPanel();
      microphonePanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      microphonePanel.add(new JLabel("Microphone:"),
         BorderLayout.NORTH);
      microphonePanel.add(microphoneField,
         BorderLayout.CENTER);
      microphonePanel.add(buttonPanel,
         BorderLayout.SOUTH);

      microphonePanel.add(scrollMic);
      final JFrame frame = new JFrame();

      frame.add(speakerPanel,
         BorderLayout.NORTH);
      frame.add(keyPanel,
         BorderLayout.CENTER);
      frame.add(microphonePanel,
         BorderLayout.SOUTH);

      // Replace the default close operation with a window event listener.
      frame.addWindowListener(new
         WindowAdapter()
         {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent event)
            {
               if (numberOfPhones == 1)
                  System.exit(0);
               else
               {
                  numberOfPhones = numberOfPhones - 1;
                  frame.dispose();
               }
            }
         });

      frame.pack();
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   /**
      Give instructions to the mail system user.
   */
   public void speak(String output)
   {
      speakerField.setText(output);
   }

   public void run(Connection c)
   {
      connect = c;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scrollSpeaker = new JScrollPane(speakerField);
speakerPanel.add(speakerField, BorderLayout.CENTER);
speakerPanel.add(scrollSpeaker);
```

A component can only have a single parent.

In your code you create the scroll pane with the text field, which is good.

But then you

1. add the text area to the panel, which removes it from the scroll pane
2. add the scroll pane to the panel, but there is nothing in the scroll pane

All you need is:

```
scrollSpeaker = new JScrollPane(speakerField);
speakerPanel.add(scrollSpeaker);
```